# Which inputenc for these Latvian letters?

Tags: input-encodings, latvian

I type in English but I need the following few Latvian letters.

Minimal case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
diņš 
\end{document}
```

which gives **di** only.

**How can you have those Latvian letters?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The letter `š` is supported by the T1 encoding and you should load

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

anyway. The “n with cedilla” is not supported by the fonts, so it must be composed. With `newunicodechar` it's pretty easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{Ņ}{\c{N}}
\newunicodechar{ņ}{\c{n}}

\begin{document}
diņš DIŅŠ
\end{document}
```

However you might prefer a comma below, instead of a cedilla.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\makeatletter
\ProvideTextCommandDefault\textlatviancommabelow[1]
  {\hmode@bgroup\ooalign{\null#1\crcr\hidewidth
     \raise-.15ex\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                       \fontsize\ssf@size\z@
                       \math@fontsfalse\selectfont,}\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother

\newunicodechar{Ņ}{\textlatviancommabelow{N}}
\newunicodechar{ņ}{\textlatviancommabelow{n}}

\begin{document}
diņš DIŅŠ
\end{document}
```

[image]

With some more work you can make the composite character copyable (provided the PDF viewer supports the feature; Adobe Reader does); the following is similar to my answer to [Unable to search word with Romanian characters in output pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42542/unable-to-search-word-with-romanian-characters-in-output-pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\makeatletter
\ProvideTextCommandDefault\textlatviancommabelow[1]
  {\hmode@bgroup\ooalign{\null#1\crcr\hidewidth
     \raise-.15ex\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                       \fontsize\ssf@size\z@
                       \math@fontsfalse\selectfont,}\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother

\newunicodechar{Ņ}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=0145}%
    \textlatviancommabelow{N}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\newunicodechar{ņ}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=0146}%
    \textlatviancommabelow{n}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\begin{document}
diņš DIŅŠ
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer with clear examples!

Comment: wouldn't inverted accent-grave be a bit better?

Comment: @tohecz I don't think so, but it depends on preferences.

Comment: In the package **europecv**, the line **\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}** causes a *Latex Error: Option clash for package inputenc.* The package seems import inputenc package itself so it seems that you cannot call inputenc -package again. I have first line of my document as *\documentclass[utf8,helvetica,narrow]{europecv}*.

Comment: @Masi The `europecv` class arbitrarily decided that `utf8` is not a good option and uses `utf8x` even if the passed option is `utf8`, which is of course stupid. I'll try finding a workaround, but it's better to make a new question.

Comment: @Masi I have a workaround (ugly). The best thing to do would be persuading the maintainer of `europecv` that using `utf8` is ***good***. A new question is surely necessary: other people might incur in the same problem.

Comment: @egreg I opened a new discussion about this here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218101/13173

Comment: This letter "š" does not work in Beamer in these settings. How can you determine the symbol explicitly like you do for the special n

Comment: @Masi The game is the usual one: open a new question with a MWE

Comment: Here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230281/13173

Answer (score 7):

UTF-8 input is fine, you just need to tell tex what to do with that character:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0146}{\c{n}}
\begin{document}
diņš 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, I would like to welcome you to current century:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % or whatever OTF you have on your system
\setmainlanguage{latvian} % loads language hyphenation rules and such

\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % or whatever math OTF you have on your system

\begin{document}
diņš
\end{document}
```

(and save your files in utf8)

Comment: I really like this answer! Kiitos! @egrep What do you think about this? I think the typography here is better. What are possible side-effects etc? I only need those Latvian characters to type the name of my university. Mostly, I am writing English. I like the math-things there too.

Comment: I set the language to be **english** as **\setmainlanguage{english}** and I still get the correct symbols for the name of my university. So "Contents" is seen correctly, and not in Latvian.

Comment: @Masi: Jūs esat laipni. (I hope Google translate did that correctly). But yes, I assumed your text would've been in Latvian, but I see you already found out how to change that :)

Comment: @Masi If you're bound to `pdflatex` this is nothing you can make profit of. If you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, of course you get the “real” glyph.

Comment: @egreg I am not bound to pdflatex. I am using XeLaTeX at the moment. It is very nice to understand these different environments. I just need the best typography for my application.

Comment: @Masi Your question assumed `pdflatex`, though.

Comment: @egrep How can you see it? I am such an newbie still that I did not intend to make such an assumption.

Comment: @Masi: I guess egreg didn't see your question because you misspelled his handle, but I think what he meant is that the line: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` would assume PDFLaTeX because you wouldn't use it with (Lua/Xe)LaTeX. Although, to know that already requires some amount of expertise. I think it would be helpful to draw some kind of diagram regarding  different engine choices and link it to our help pages.

Comment: @morbusg Can you draw such a diagram? Or know any sources? It would be very useful.

Comment: @Masi: yes, I'll work something out and put it on meta for discussion.

Comment: @morbusg Please, point me to a link when it is done or started.

Answer (score 2):

It's the older version: `utf8x`, but this works with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
diņš 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend loading `utf8x`

Comment: @egreg: I know... it's outdated

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ... it’s outdated, but it works here.  if the user agrees to sign a declaration that he’ll never use the package elsewhere, perhaps he should be allowed to use it.  after all, it saves him typing.  (in fact, errors with utf8x are pretty rare, so they tend to “throw” us when they do appear.)