# To type these math declares in XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex

I am converting my codes from pdflatex to XeLaTeX

Minimal case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % or whatever OTF you have on your system
\setmainlanguage{english} % loads language hyphenation rules and such
\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % or whatever math OTF you have on your 
% Problem with these declarations which I like to use
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\norm{x} + \abs{y} = 1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

where I had previously

```
% \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp, mathtools, xparse}
% \usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
```

**What is the correct way of having these declarations in XeLaTeX?**

### Some challenges with Egreg's [approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218102/13173)

Example data

```
\begin{equation}
\norm{x} + \abs{y} = 1 is \norm{x} + \abs{y} = 1 \square.
\end{equation}
```

I can resolve these errors by this

```
\usepackage{mathtools, xparse} % load mathtools before loading fontspec
% amsmath never needed with mathtools
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp} % not sure if these are necessary
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213430/13173
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % or whatever OTF you have on your system
\setmainlanguage{english} % loads language hyphenation rules and such
\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % or whatever math OTF you have on your system
```

where I cannot understand which is the critical package. 
I think `xparse` is needed but it does not solve the square-symbol -challenge when used this package with Egreg's code.

Comment: fontenc you don't need, amsmath you never needed if you load mathtools, so you should just be able to load mathtools and xparse as before. did you get any specific errors with them?

Comment: Since `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` is provided by `mathtools`, you have to load it. Put it *before* loading `fontspec`. But, please, do some research before asking questions.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment which is also a right answer! I will study this issue more, since now, I have a need for good typography.

Comment: @Masi, please cite the errors as well. Hard to debug when one does not have the specific fonts.

Comment: I moved the other problem to this discussion http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218121/13173 to make things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` is defined by `mathtools`. Since this package also loads `amsmath` it must go *before* `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec
\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths

\setmainlanguage{english} % loads language hyphenation rules and such

\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % or whatever OTF you have on your system
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % or whatever math OTF you have on your 

% Problem with these declarations which I like to use
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\norm{x} + \abs{y} = 1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Let's assume this line **\norm{x} + \abs{y} = 1** is **\norm{x} + \abs{y} = 1 \square**. Which package you need for this symbol?

Comment: This is strange. *Mathtools* should load *amsmath* which should have *\square* -symbol.

Comment: @Masi, no, there are *TWO* AMS packages, `mathtools` only load `amsmath`, extra symbols are loaded via `amssymb`. Usually you load both

Comment: @daleif amssymb does not work in my case for some reason. I tried it. Trying reproduce.

Comment: @masi, then please update your questing with the log of that error. I do not have any of the fonts used here, but loading `amssymb` alongside `mathtools` and commenting out the two `\setm...` font loading macros, then `\square` works just fine for me.

Comment: @daleif I cannot reproduce the thing by commenting out setmainfont and setmathfont. You can post your edits as an answer if they work in your system.

Comment: @Masi Don't load `amssymb` along with `unicode-math`; it's that simple.

Comment: @egreg How can you have then otherwise the square -symbol?

Comment: @Masi U+25A1 WHITE SQUARE; in unicode-math it is `\mdlgwhtsquare`; or U+25AB WHITE SMALL SQUARE called `\smwhtsquare`

Answer (score 2):

In relation to the extra question about `\square`. I do not have Minion Pro, but out commenting the two `\setm...` font lines and adding `amssymb`, then  this compiles just fine using `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec
\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths

\setmainlanguage{english} % loads language hyphenation rules and such

%\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % or whatever OTF you have on your system
%\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % or whatever math OTF you have on your 

% Problem with these declarations which I like to use
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\norm{x} + \abs{y} = 1 \square
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right! This works for the square! I am now thinking the other case where math in the section's title.

Comment: That also work in this example. Now you see why we ask for the error messages or the entire log file?

Comment: This one **\section{Complex pathogenesis $\to$ complicated classification}** ?

Comment: Compiles just fine. Please update your question with the contents of the `.log` file.

Comment: Yes, I did so. Log is here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218121/13173