# This Question environment with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, mdframed, mac

I am still converting my pdflatex codes to XeLaTeX.

Minimal case

```
\documentclass{article}

% The Question -environment works with these two lines
% \usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp, mathtools, xparse}
% \usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213457/13173
\usepackage{mathtools, xparse} % load mathtools before loading fontspec
% amsmath never needed with mathtools
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp} % not sure if these are necessary
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213430/13173
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % or whatever OTF you have on your system
\setmainlanguage{english} % loads language hyphenation rules and such
\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % or whatever math OTF you have on your system

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
% Problem here
% This environment do not work with the above packages    
\mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
  linecolor=cyan,
  backgroundcolor=yellow!20,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=green!40,
    frametitlerule=true
}
\newcounter{question}[section]%
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newenvironment{question}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{question}%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=ans,frametitle={Question: #1}]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
{Is this Lorem Ipsun?}
Yes, it is. 
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

where the *mdframed* -package seems to designed with pdflatex, since it works with the two lines (7) and (8).

The strange errors

[image]

suggests me that the new packages do not understand the syntax which I have used with Question -environment.

Errors and warnings are like this

```
*************************************************
* unicode-math warning: "mathtools-overbracket"
* 
* Using \overbracket and \underbracke from `mathtools' package.
* 
* Use \Uoverbracket and \Uunderbracke for original `unicode-math' definition.
*************************************************
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
./test.tex:41: Too many }'s.
\endmdf@lrbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup 

l.41 \end{question}


Package mdframed Warning: The environment is empty
(mdframed)                 on input line 41.

./test.tex:41: Extra \endgroup.
\color@endgroup ->\endgraf \endgroup 

l.41 \end{question}


./test.tex:41: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{mdframed}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.41 \end{question}

./test.tex:41: Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.41 \end{question}


./test.tex:41: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{question}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.41 \end{question}

./test.tex:41: Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.41 \end{question}

[1] (/Users/masi/Desktop/.texpadtmp/test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on /Users/masi/Desktop/.texpadtmp/test.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on /Users/masi/Desktop/.texpadtmp/test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/masi/Desktop/.texpadtmp/test.log.
```

Output of `\listfiles`

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
mathtools.sty    2013/02/12 v1.13 mathematical typesetting tools
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2010/01/21 v1.2a programming setup (MH)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  xparse.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2014/01/07 v4646 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2014/01/04 v4640 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2013/12/27 v4625 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2013/08/02 v4583 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2013/08/25 v4587 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2013/12/14 v4623 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2013/10/13 v4596 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2013/12/08 v4614 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2014/01/04 v4642 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2013/12/14 v4624 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2013/07/28 v4581 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2014/01/06 v4643 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
polyglossia.sty    2013/06/27 v1.33.4 Babel replacement for XeLaTeX and LuaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
fontspec.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2013/05/20 v2.3c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
gloss-english.ldf    polyglossia: module for english
unicode-math.sty    2013/05/04 v0.7e Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
l3keys2e.sty    2013/12/31 v4634 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  fix-cm.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
unicode-math-xetex.sty    
unicode-math-table.tex
mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
needspace.sty    2010/09/12 v1.3d reserve vertical space
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
md-frame-1.mdf    2013/07/01\ 1.9b: md-frame-1
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
 ***********

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on /Users/masi/Desktop/.texpadtmp/test.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on /Users/masi/Desktop/.texpadtmp/test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/masi/Desktop/.texpadtmp/test.log.
```

**How can you convert this Question -environment from pdflatex to XeLaTeX in mdframed?**

Comment: I get no error.

Comment: @egreg I added completely what I get in XeLaTeX. You are probably in Linux, are you? I am on OSX.

Comment: I am on OS X too. I just commented out the lines with the font names, which surely aren't the problem. I get no error.

Comment: @Masi the operating systen is not relevant but package versions might be, add `\listfiles` to your preamble and post the list that gets printed.

Comment: I think @egreg is on Windows

Comment: If you are on osx, how come you are loading cambria math?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Office is also available for Mac :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the output of my **\listfiles**.

Comment: several of your packages are out dated. If you update the error goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I change Minion pro (which I don't have) it runs without error in texlive 2014.
If I add `\listfiles` I get the list below (which is why this is posted as an answer, to format the list:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
mathtools.sty    2014/07/16 v1.15 mathematical typesetting tools
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2010/01/21 v1.2a programming setup (MH)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  xparse.sty    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2014/09/15 v5423 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3unicode-data.def    2014/08/12 v5276 L3 Unicode data
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
polyglossia.sty    2014/05/21 v1.33.5 Babel replacement for XeLaTeX and LuaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
 xkeyval.sty    2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
fontspec.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fontspec-xetex.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2014/07/25 v4.03 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
gloss-english.ldf    polyglossia: module for english
unicode-math.sty    2014/06/30 v0.7f Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
l3keys2e.sty    2014/09/15 v5423 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  fix-cm.sty    2014/08/30 v1.1s fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
unicode-math-xetex.sty    
unicode-math-table.tex
mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
needspace.sty    2010/09/12 v1.3d reserve vertical space
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
md-frame-1.mdf    2013/07/01\ 1.9b: md-frame-1
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
 ***********
```

Comment: Your texlive is newer. Are you on Mac? I am using these packages https://tug.org/mactex/ I am on Yosemite which may be a problem. Have not reinstalled the packages again.

Comment: @Masi I'm not on a mac but that's not relevant. If you have errors due to bugs that are fixed in later versions of packages, there is likely to be limited enthusiasm to try to work out what the problem is. Why not update?

Comment: I am updating all the time by installing MacTex again. Let's see if it is enough. I am not sure how active project that is.

Comment: @Masi the link you give is to mactex 2014 but that is texlive 2014. the files you have are older than that. Probably texlive 2013 with some updates.

Comment: @Masi mactex is actively updated (and probably what egreg was using) you need to run tlmgr once it is installed to update packages. But you have the 1999 keyval so you have not got texlive 2014.

Comment: I think that is the problem. I have never run **tlmgr** after the upgrade. Although I think I have run the update process of MacTex 2014 before.

Comment: I run the update, and now, I am running tlmgr update --all.

Comment: Works! After binding with tmlgr. Thank you for your answer!