# Why pagesel prevents refs and cites updated?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, pagesel

Minimum code where the `pagesel` command prevents refs and cites be updated. 
I would like to understand why

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

%% PDFTeX
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218102/13173
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{pgffor}            

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[1-]{pagesel}

\begin{document}

Fig. \ref{figure:ba_sinus_female}, 

\begin{figure}
\foreach \ii in {2,...,2}{
\centering% not \center!
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.16, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 1.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.16, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 2.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.16, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 3.}
\end{subfigure}
}
\caption{Bland.}
\label{figure:ba_sinus_female}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I add `\ref{figure:cor_gender}` I get 1 (after double run of LaTeX).

Comment: Sorry? Why should you use two underscores if the label has one?

Comment: Of course there's no difference so long as you use the same tokens in `\ref` as for `\label`.

Comment: @egreg I still cannot get any refs work in to such environments. Please, see the list of packages which I use. Can there by anything which may be the reason for the case?

Comment: Why don't you make a *single self-contained* example that presents the error?

Comment: @egreg Please, see the body. I think the problem becomes from the fact that I have very many for loops in my body about 7 with each 1-2 iterations. Decreasing the file size, the problem disappears if I run the pdflatex many times. However, including many such loops causes the failure. Can you confirm? - - Is there any workaround for the problem? - - To compile bib and refs separately from for-loops?

Comment: You have a complete minimal example, the start of an overly complicated example, and then a long non-complete example that you say exhibits the error.  Which one causes the problem?  Give us a single example that we can copy, paste, compile four times, and still see the error.

Comment: @Masi: If you have a number of iterations all having the same `\label`, you'll have multiply-defined `\label`s.

Comment: See the body. I found the issue. Pagesel prevents updating those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 1.2.1 in the manual for `pagesel`:

```
\usepackage[files,1-]{pagesel}
```

Without the `files` option, the `.aux` file is not written.

Alternatively, process the document with the call to `pagesel` commented out, then uncomment and reprocess.