# How to have this Latvian letter "s" with top "nose"?

Tags: xetex, input-encodings, latvian

This discussion is an extension of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213324/13173) but in Beamer -documentclass and with XeLaTeX. 
I can get some variants working there in Pdflatex, see Christian's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213318/13173) but with bad output and I do not want it, since I lose the nice layout what XeLaTeX can offer.

Code based on [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213324/4427) and which I think offers the best extensibility to solve this problem here in XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}   
š
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Any options offered in the above discussion are not working XeLaTeX.

Output nothing.

Comment: If you don't supply a definition for š, what do you expect?

Comment: Yes, and how to supply that one. In the other class, it worked without explicit newunicodechar definition, but not in Beamer. I do not understand the difference between the two documentclasses.

Comment: Why are you using XeLaTeX, if you're not using any of its features? Besides, where's `beamer` used? Please, make an example that really reflects what you want.

Comment: Why not just use `\v{s}` again?

Comment: you have tagged the question xetex and beamer, but the example doesn't use beamer at all and inputenc will give a warning that it should not be used with xetex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My mistake in the body. Typed it fast. Of course, in beamer.

Comment: but still, don't use inputenc with xtex

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230281/to-have-this-latvian-letter-in-beamer

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230281/to-have-this-latvian-letter-in-beamer/231242#231242?newreg=e280a8635f06415f9f6310337d6fbaeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to do it without `fontspec`. Use simply

```
\v{s}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `fontspec` if you want to use XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
š and math $a+b=c$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]