# diacritic marks in formulas

Tags: equations, fontspec

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Ārā
\begin{equation}
  \Phi_{Ārā}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I use xelatex to compile this code containing Latvian characters - see [Which inputenc for these Latvian letters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213316/which-inputenc-for-these-latvian-letters)

The output is the following

[image]

The letters with diacritic marks are displayed correctly in text but are missing in the formula. How to fix?

Comment: This is a stupid bug/design flaw in TeX: when characters are missing in a font, it thinks it's something non-serious to hide in the log file. See [Getting XeTeX to complain when a character is missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/getting-xetex-to-complain-when-a-character-is-missing). IMO one should always put `\tracinglostchars=2` at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `\mathrm` or `\text` for this. But don't overuse diacritic in math, they can be confused with accents like \bar and so change the mathematical meaning.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Ārā
\begin{equation}
  \Phi_{\mathrm{Ārā}} \Phi_{\text{\normalfont Ārā}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably don't want that text in math italic anyway. use the `amsmath` package and the `\text` command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Ārā
\begin{equation}
  \Phi_{\text{Ārā}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```