# Special characters using XeLatex (š,č,ž)

Tags: characters

I am writing a CV, using the XeLaTeX template below:
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/professional-cv

When I include special characters like č,ž,š, it left blank space in the output PDF.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}
%%%

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

I tried to use package

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{slovenian}
```

but I still got blank space.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Welcome! What does the console output or log file say? Please provide a complete but minimal example we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You appear to be using the Fontin font family. Does Fontin provide glyphs for `č`, `ž`, and `š`? The version of this font that's installed on my system (version 001.000, from 2004; admittedly, this may not be the latest version) does not provide such glyphs.

Comment: I just deleated

    \setmainfont[
    SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
    BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
    ]
{Fontin.otf}
and now all special characters work.

Comment: @TimotejMrzelj - So, which font are you using instead of `Fontin`? Just the default font, which would be `Latin Modern`?

Comment: `polyglossia` doesn't do anything for font-handling btw

Answer (score 1):

That is (as mentioned in the comments) very probably just a font-issue.

The *Fontin* I could [download here](https://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html) just doesn't have the required glyphs with diacritics from [Latin Extended A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A). The font only contains most of [Latin 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)) and some odd others.

With most fonts you can leave it to `fontspec` to find italic and bold styles. 
On the other hand the above-mentioned version of *Fontin* (and quite some other fonts available) doesn't use proper naming for its small-caps font, so you need to call *this* explicitly.

Also the file-extension is usually superfluous and often (at least on my OS) even disruptive.

```
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps,
]
{Fontin}
```

works for me -- for Western alphabets, that is.

Answer (score -2):

Note: For Pdflatex but still load some xelatex packages

Code where disabled your font because I do not have it and added the three first packages there

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213324/13173
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
%\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
%\setmainfont[
%SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
%BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
%ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
%]
%{Fontin.otf}
%%%

%CV Sections inspired by: 
%http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/26
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

%Italian hyphenation for the word: ''corporations''
\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

%-------------WATERMARK TEST [**not part of a CV**]---------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Ž

š,č,ž

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Your answer isn't very good. The OP is using a unicode engine, you are providing an answer for pdflatex and still load packages unsuitable (i.e. for use with xelatex).

Comment: @Johannes_B Which packages should be removed here for Pdflatex proposal?